# react js how to add box counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add box in a counter in react js counter, but I do not know how to add in this application. I tried a lot after counter using react box material.

Here is my code of app.js like as this image shown:

[image: toystore counter box add]

`

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);//initial value is in parenthesis
  return (
    <div className="container my-10">
      <div className="card text-center my-5">
        <div className="card-body">
        <h1>Counter App</h1>
        <div className="my-5">
          <h2 className="my-5">{count}</h2>
          <div className="text-right">
          <button
                className="text-right rounded-circle btn btn-success mx-3"
                onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}>+</button>
          <button
                  className="rounded-circle btn btn-success mx-3"
                  onClick={() => setCount(count-1)}
                  disabled={count === 0}>-</button>
          <Button type="reset"
            onClick={() => setCount(0)}
            disabled={count === 0}>Reset</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What is a box counter? You want to increment/decrement some count state? Isn't that what the code does already? Can you clarify what the issue is? Is this for an assignment?

Comment: like as in the image show i have the + - button when i can click on on + button the box will add in - box will decrement. but now tried all of things but i can not able to add box in this counter format . no for self practice

Comment: What does "add box in this counter format" mean? It's unclear what you are asking for and it's unclear what any issue is with the code example.

Comment: means it will add box  or new toy box add when we click on + button basically how i can do that

Comment: can you help me in this ?? or now u can not understand

Comment: Create an array of length equal to the `count` state and map it to JSX as-per-usual. Where are you trying to render these boxes? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service nor is it a tutoring service. We can answer very specific, on-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-mclean-iuh9ig?file=/src/App.js:0-1415

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0); //initial value is in parenthesis
  return (
    <div className="container my-10">
      <div className="card text-center my-5">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h1>Counter App</h1>
          <div className="my-5">
            <h2 className="my-5">{count}</h2>
            <div className="text-right">
              <button
                className="text-right rounded-circle btn btn-success mx-3"
                onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
              >
                +
              </button>
              <button
                className="rounded-circle btn btn-success mx-3"
                onClick={() => {
                  if (count > 0) {
                    setCount(count - 1);
                  }
                }}
                disabled={count === 0}
              >
                -
              </button>
              <Button
                type="reset"
                onClick={() => setCount(0)}
                disabled={count === 0}
              >
                Reset
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
          {[...Array(count).keys()].map((item) => (
            <div className="card">box {item + 1}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: yes tq so much now i can know how to add that box basically card